Oracle Apex AnyChart... if then statement in the XML? Is it possible
I am trying to get decimals to show for certain chart data, but not for others.  The user can choose a measure to chart from a select list.  For example, a dollar amount would not need two decimals.  But if they pick a percentage, it needs to have two decimals.  In the attached screen shot, you can see that decimals are not necessary.

However, in the next screen shot, you can see how I need decimal places:

Since this is a legacy AnyChart, I'm looking at the XML code window to see if I can maybe do an if... then statement of some kind?  Possibly in this section:
<format><![CDATA[{%Name}{enabled:False} - {%Value}{numDecimals:2,decimalSeparator:.,thousandsSeparator:\,}]]></format>

But I may be doing this the hard way.  I tried to make my chart a multi-series chart but only one series would show at a time.  I had to make it a Legacy AnyChart to get more than one series to show.  So, this is two parter:  Can I do an if...then... statement in XML?  Or, how do I get more than one series to show at a time in a "multi-series" chart?  I need it to look like the first picture above.  Thank you!

I'd go with two charts (or more, if necessary): one would display dollars, another one percentage.

format each region the way you want (with decimals, without them, whatever)

set the select list item to submit the page

create server-side condition for each chart region; for example, a function body for the 1st region:
return :P1_SELECT_LIST := 'dollars';



Initially, when you enter the page, select list item won't have any value so none of chart region will be displayed. Then, as you select something and submit the page, server-side condition for one of regions will be satisfied and that region will be displayed. If you select something else, another region will be displayed and other(s) won't.
